# Reading HTML class with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

[image]

```
<div class="countdownHolder"> <span class="countMinutes"> <span class="position"> <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;">0</span> </span> <span class="position"> <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;">0</span> </span> </span> <span class="countDiv countDiv0">:</span> <span class="countSeconds"> <span class="position"> <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;">4</span> </span> <span class="position"> <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;">0</span> </span> </span> </div>
```

Im trying to read the value highlighted in this image, Not quite sure how to get to it from where i am.

Function

```
private HtmlElement[] GetElementsByClassName(WebBrowser wb, string tagName, string className)
{
    var l = new System.Collections.Generic.List<HtmlElement>();

    if (wb != null && wb.Document != null)
    {
        var els = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tagName);
        foreach (HtmlElement el in els)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("className") == className)
            {
                l.Add(el);
            }
        }
    }

    return l.ToArray();
}
```

How im calling it, It seems to find countdownHolder class

```
var countdownHolder = GetElementsByClassName(_webBrowser, "div", "countdownHolder");
if (countdownHolder.Length != 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer but I would suggest a strategy:

```
var countdownHolder = GetElementsByClassName(_webBrowser, "div", "countdownHolder");
foreach (var element in countdownHolder.ToList())
{
    //  inspect element here
}
```

`GetElementsByClassName` works.

UPDATED:

The following should give you what you want.

```
foreach (var element in countdownHolder)
{
    var item1 = element.InnerText; //or
    var item2 = element.OuterText; //both give the same answer here
    // do something
}
```

In general, review the properties of `element`

**UPDATE 2:**

The actual structure is:

```
<div class='countdownHolder'> 
    <span class='countMinutes'> 
        <span class='position'> 
            <span class='digit static' style='top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;'>
                0
            </span> 
        </span> 
        <span class='position'> 
            <span class='digit static' style='top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;'>
            0
            </span> 
        </span> 
    </span> 
    <span class='countDiv countDiv0'>
        :
    </span> 
    <span class='countSeconds'> 
        <span class='position'> 
            <span class='digit static' style='top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;'>
                4
            </span> 
        </span> 
        <span class='position'> 
            <span class='digit static' style='top: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: 350ms ease;'>
                0
            </span> 
        </span> 
    </span> 
</div>
```

The embedded text gives minutes and seconds with a `:` as separator. In this example `00:40`. With the additional spaces: `0 0 : 4 0`

All you need now is simple string handling. You can do this in a variety of ways. `string time = element.InnerText.Replace(" ", "");` will remove the spaces. There are then a number of different ways to process the resulting the `min:sec` structure

Comment: Im not 100% sure on what functions to use to read each part on the HTML

Comment: i can see all the classes that i want to work with in GetElementsByClassName my problem is im not sure how to walk down all the classes from there to find my value, as you can see GetElementsByClassName HtmlDocument not sure how to pass that from each element

Comment: The real Html is a website and its huge

Comment: posted it above, not sure how to copy it on diff lines

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: foe some reason that is giving me a string like this `"0  0   : 4  0   "` not to sure why

Comment: Its close to what i wanted, but i was trying to read the seconds only, not the full text like `"0 0 : 4 0 "` not sure how to remove the spaces and all that stuff, would like the data in a int if i could